# Powershell code to print/break lines after each value read from text file

Tags: powershell, newline, patch, line-breaks

I am trying to create a script that gets all the servers' patch installations in our environment. The script I am running is giving me continuous output without printing any success messages after each server read from text file. I have written a fairly basic script! Doh.

I want to insert some code into my script which, either prints each server details with a Break / Success message before printing another server continuously in CLI, or prints each server in a separate text file. Please find the below Code:

`$Computers = gc ServerListFile.txt`

`Get-hotfix -computer $Computers`

Please give me some input at least, to try and get it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is accepting the `$Computers` variable as a `string` instead of a `string[]` (array).

You need to put it through a loop to specify a newline after each set of hotfixes:

```
$computers = gc ServerListFile.txt
ForEach ($computer in $computers) {

    # You could even put the computer name at the beginning of the hotfixes
    "Hotfixes for $($computer)" | Out-File hotfixes.log -a -en ASCII

    # Get the hotfixes and output to text file
    Get-Hotfix -computer $computer | Out-File hotfixes.log -a -en ASCII

    # Add a new line after each computer's hotfixes
    "`n" | Out-File hotfixes.log -a -en ASCII
}
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot! But this is resulting the same way. All I wanted is to get break points after each server output in cli itself or to pipe it to text file with line breaks between each server output.

Comment: Changed my answer, is that what you meant?

Comment: Brilliant! You are just brilliant. Awesome... You just saved my day. You rock @Vasili Syrakis

Comment: Can you please help me on this Question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654524/vbscript-code-to-read-input-from-text-file-avoiding-manual-efforts