# VB Script that needs to read from a text file

Tags: vbscript, scripting

I have a VB Script that goes out to a string of servers and checks to see if there are any pending Windows updates.  It works perfectly.  The only issue is to run the script I have to type:
cscript pending.vbs server01 server02 server03 server04 etc..  I have over 300 servers I want to run this against.  I need to be able to update a text file with server names instead of manually typing them out.  I am posting the script below:
I am not a programmer by far, but I do understand some.

Thanks!

```
'#
'# ServerPendingUpdates.vbs
'#
'# Usage: cscript ServerPendingUpdates.vbs {servername} {servername} {servername} {servername}
'#    If no {servername} specified then 'localhost' assumed
'#
'# To do: Error handling
'#
Option Explicit
Dim strServer        : strServer         =  GetArgValue(0,"localhost")


'#
'# Loop through the input parameters for each server
'#
Dim i
For i = 0 To WScript.Arguments.Count - 1
    CheckServerUpdateStatus GetArgValue(i,"localhost") 'strServer
Next

WScript.Quit(0)

Function CheckServerUpdateStatus( ByVal strServer )

    WScript.Echo vbCRLF & "Connecting to " & strServer & " to check software update status..."

    Dim blnRebootRequired    : blnRebootRequired     = False
    Dim blnRebootPending    : blnRebootPending     = False
    Dim objSession        : Set objSession    = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session", strServer)
    Dim objUpdateSearcher     : Set objUpdateSearcher    = objSession.CreateUpdateSearcher
    Dim objSearchResult    : Set objSearchResult     = objUpdateSearcher.Search(" IsAssigned=1 and IsHidden=0 and Type='Software'")

    '#
    '#
    '#
    Dim i, objUpdate
    Dim intPendingInstalls    : intPendingInstalls     = 0

    For i = 0 To objSearchResult.Updates.Count-1
        Set objUpdate = objSearchResult.Updates.Item(I) 

        If objUpdate.IsInstalled Then
            If objUpdate.RebootRequired Then
                blnRebootPending     = True
            End If
        Else
            intPendingInstalls    = intPendingInstalls + 1
            'If objUpdate.RebootRequired Then    '### This property is FALSE before installation and only set to TRUE after installation to indicate that this patch forced a reboot.
            If objUpdate.InstallationBehavior.RebootBehavior <> 0 Then
                '# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386064%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
                '# InstallationBehavior.RebootBehavior = 0    Never reboot
                '# InstallationBehavior.RebootBehavior = 1    Must reboot
                '# InstallationBehavior.RebootBehavior = 2    Can request reboot
                blnRebootRequired     = True
            End If

        End If
    Next

    WScript.Echo strServer & " has " & intPendingInstalls & " updates pending installation"

    If blnRebootRequired Then
        WScript.Echo strServer & " WILL need to be rebooted to complete the installation of these updates."
    Else
        WScript.Echo strServer & " WILL NOT require a reboot to install these updates."
    End If


    '#
    '#
    '#
    If blnRebootPending Then
        WScript.Echo strServer & " is waiting for a REBOOT to complete a previous installation."
    End If 
End Function



'#
'#
'#
Function GetArgValue( intArgItem, strDefault )
    If WScript.Arguments.Count > intArgItem Then
        GetArgValue = WScript.Arguments.Item(intArgItem)
    Else
        GetArgValue = strDefault
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [vbscript code to read input from text file avoiding manual efforts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654524/vbscript-code-to-read-input-from-text-file-avoiding-manual-efforts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query all domain using an ASDI object in vbs:

```
Set DomObj = GetObject("WinNT://" & strDomain )
DomObj.Filter = Array("computer")
```

Will output an array (DomObj)

or use LDAP:

```
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
strQuery = "<LDAP://" & strDNSDomain & "> (objectCategory=computer);distinguishedName,operatingSystem;subtree"
```

Source:
http://www.scriptlook.com/list-servers-domain/ & 
http://www.scriptlook.com/check-services-every-server-domain/

Answer (score 0):

Just create a text file with the list of servers, one per line. 
Open the file (OpenTextFile) and read it line by line. See these links for reference

http://ss64.com/vb/filesystemobject.html

[FileSystemObject Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

```
path = "serverlist.txt"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(path, 1)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  CheckServerUpdateStatus(objFile.ReadLine)
Loop
```

Comment: Is this going to take place of a section in the script?

Comment: yes, it can replace the section between 'Dim i' and 'Next' near the start

Comment: I added the code where you told me and I am getting an error about 'path' not being defined:

Dim i
path = "machines.txt"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(path, 1)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  CheckServerUpdateStatus(objFile.ReadLine)
Loop

Comment: remove also Dim i, so that the line starts with path = "machines.txt"

Comment: I feel like I am close.  It gets to the point its looking at the file, but this is what I am getting:

Connecting to y_H
runtime error:  The remote server machine does not exist.. I am not sure where its getting the y_H?

Comment: The contents of the file should only be the exact server names on a line by themself e.g. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=gDA71jux